# “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <” when adding callback to external feed call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, feed

I am trying to pull a password protected xml feed from another website, but I am getting the following error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

I fixed the origin access error that I was getting previously by adding a callback function, but now I am getting this uncaught syntax error.

My code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx.php?&callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'POST',
    username: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    crossDomain : true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

When I inspect the error I can just see 'denied' where the feed should be: [screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yAcF.png)

Any ideas why this is not working? Do I need to request something from the feed provider? Or is there something missing/incorrect in my code?

Comment: Surprisingly, JSONP is not XML ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You try to load an `xml` and use `dataType: 'jsonp'`. jQuery can't handle the response because you tell the `$.ajax` function to use the response as `JSONP`. So the first char of the response `<` is unexpected.

Use `dataType: 'xml'` instead.

The `denied` seems to come from a wrong login too. Are you sure the `username` and `password` options are working for you? I got many problems using it this way. I would pefer to change your login to use `beforeSend`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx.php?&callback=?',
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain : true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for you comment. I have made the changes as suggested, but now I am getting another origin access error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.xxx.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405."

Comment: That sounds like the resource under `xxx.php` has no `CORS` headers set. Are you sure this is a public api, accessible by AJAX? The resource need to have these headers, if you want to use them with AJAX. Otherwise browsers will block the handling because of security reasons. Contact the owner of the resource. @JWhy